# compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+' i am geting error on this line in my android gradle file

Tags: android

[image]

I am building my first google maps app but when I added 
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+' 
in my gradile file it gets red . what can be the issue and solution to solve it

Comment: You should not be using `+` in your dependency versions

Comment: then what should a use at the place of +

Comment: @UmairAziz the latest. like 26.1.0

Comment: whatever version of the library you want to use. The current version of the support library is `26.1.0` and your google play services version is very old

Comment: What is the error message that are you getting when you put your mouse over that line?